# Display an image from the database in Django?

Tags: mysql, database, django, image

I have a read only db that I don't have the ability to change. I know that it is extremely inefficient to store images in a database. However I don't have control over this one. I need to display the image from the field in the database. How can you do this in Django?

Comment: Perhaps: http://www.kodevelopment.nl/blog/?p=25 ?

Comment: I'm trying to display the image in a template not upload it. How can you retrieve it?

Comment: As @John Mee mentioned below, you would need to retrieve the file back and render it to the response. Alternatively, if you follow the Blog post link above and add a "BlobField" to your model, you should be able to work with the file in a much more convenient, Django-esque way. The BlobField from the example is going to use StringIO to get the contents into a more usable form for you.

Comment: @Brandon link is dead???

Comment: @ashim888 That link is *ancient* This is the latest: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects

Comment: @Brandon Thanks That was quick cheers

Answer (score 0):

1. Retrieve the image from the database as a binary,
2. write that directly into the http response content (with StringIO?),
3. set the relevant image mimetype/header

Don't forget to set the content length in the response. Experiement with 'streaming' if the images are huge.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects

Comment: Can you provide a simple example?

Comment: @brandonmhp I won't write it for you but if you post what you have tried I might be inspired enough to help you get it working.